# Microsoft Ads - Variable Revenue Conversion Goal with Shopify not working

Tags: shopify, bing-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I have gone through the help pages to set up a Purchase Conversion goal with variable revenue on Microsoft Advertising for a Shopify store. It is a "Destination URL" type goal. Although I am following the guidance to the letter, it doesn't work and I can see it doesn't work for many others from my reading.

For reference, Microsofts help page is here:

https://help.ads.microsoft.com/#apex/ads/en/56901/-1

I paste my UET tag firstly on theme.liquid directly above {{ content_for_header }} at the end of the head section in Shopify.

Next I go to settings>Checkout>Order Status Page>Additional Scripts - I paste my UET tag here also.

I also paste the following script in the >Additional scripts box below the main UET which represents the /thank_you page post purchase as far as I can see. Note, I do not have Shopify plus so cannot modify checkout.liquid.

Code below (from Microsoft Help Page) and this is to exclude shipping and taxes:

window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
   window.uetq.push('event', '', { 'revenue_value': {{ subtotal_price | money_without_currency }}, 'currency': '{{ shop.currency }}' });

I have included a screenshot of the end of the Test that I have run to Test the goal through MS Ads.
I have also included the Inspected page showing the script present and taking the correct variable revenue excl. taxes and shipping and also the correct currency.

[Conversion Goal Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hxOC.png)
[Script on Thank you Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1W8G.png)

Thank you for your help in advance. I have looked at all the youtube videos and none of the experts actually tested the goal to prove that it works.

Microsoft support pages all point back to the Shopify UET help page which has been implemented.